# How to block VNC clients' mouses and keyboards?

Tags: vnc, blocking

Could you tell me how to block VNC clients' mouses and keyboards? It means that clients can only watch activities happening at the remote computer, not participate in.

UPDATE: Wil said that it depends on the VNC variant. In my situation, the remote computer is actually a Xen (or VMware, KVM) virtual machine, so I considered using the hypervisor's built-in VNC server. However, I haven't been obliged to use any specific one yet, so please feel free to suggest what you know.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what VNC varient you are currently using.

Many VNC programs have an option for `Viewer Only`, `Disable remote events` or similar.

Here are the options for RealVNC on Windows:
[image]
So, let us know what you are using and we can try to be more specific to help you!

Comment: In my situation, the remote computer is actually a Xen (or VMware, KVM) virtual machine, so I considered using the hypervisor's built-in VNC server. However, I haven't been obliged to use any specific one yet, so please feel free to suggest what you know. Thanks.